# How can I use other files from another folder in CSS?

Tags: html, css, jsp

```
WebContent
 - image
     - 123.jpg
 - file.css
```

How can I use 123.jpg on file.css? None of the ways that I've found on the internet seem to work. Below are the ways that I've tried that didn't work:

```
    body {
     background-image: url("image/123.gif");
     background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    body {
     background-image: url("/image/123.gif");
     background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    body {
     background-image: url("../image/123.gif");
     background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    body {
     background-image: url(image/123.gif);
     background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    body {
     background-image: url(/image/123.gif);
     background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    body {
     background-image: url(../image/123.gif);
     background-color: #cccccc;
    }
```

I've also tried adding the absolute path of the file but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Even when I use my fonts in fonts folder, it doesn't work. But it works if I put the files outside the folder (the same folder with the .css file that uses the font files)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `./images/123.gif`. But are your sure your CSS file is loaded?

Check :

- The way tour file are served. Try [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) if you have a static project instead of opening your html file manually
- Your folder structure
- The network status for each ressources loaded via your browser

Comment: It still didn't work. How do I check the network status for each ressources loaded via your browser?